# what is the order of bean loading if I have multiple configuration files in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, spring-annotations

I have three configuration files in spring application.

```
@Configuration
public class FooConfig { ... }

@Configuration
public class BarConfig { ... }

@Configuration
public class FooBarConfig { ... }
```

what is the order in which the beans are loaded? can I use a `bean` defined in `FooConfig` in `BarConfig` and vice versa?

**EDIT**

This works fine as is. But my doubt is whether it works because of chance. There is an ambiguity here since different configuration files are used and the order in which they are resolved is important for proper bean loading.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @DaveNewton: it worked fine. But my doubt is whether it worked fine because of chance. there is ambiguity as different configuration files are resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please have a look at [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-injecting-imported-beans)

You can use Dependency injection  `@Autowired` to refer to beans declared on other java configuration classes but still it can be ambiguous to determine  where exactly the autowired bean definitions are declared and the solution for that is to use  `@Import`

```
@Configuration
@Import({FooConfig.class, FooBarConfig .class})
public class FooBarConfig { 
//use Autowire to import bean declared in both FooConfig and FooBarConfig
 }
```

**Edit:**
As for the order if bean A depends on bean B, you are guaranteed that B will be instantiated before A,if there is no dependendy-injection to maitain that order a trick or a workaround is to inject an unused dependency using `@Resource`.

Comment: I am not asking a way to get it to work. I edited my question above. please have a look